# how to enable to edit existing transaction in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

i should edit existing transaction. but it is giving

> **frm-40208 :** form is running in query only mode.

can not change database fields. How to escape from this error?

Regards,

Comment: perhaps you have some settings to block editing like `update_allowed`, `insert_allowed` properties inside some triggers like `PRE-FORM` or `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` ...

Comment: in trigger when-new-form-instance setted update_allowed, insert_allowed property true, anyway giving frm-40208

Answer (score 3):

You called the form in query only mode such as

```
call_form('myForm.fmx',hide,no_replace,query_only,pl_id);
```

You should check the call to this form